# replaceAll in JavaScript for loop is too slow, looking for an alternative approach

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, replace

I'm making a browser extension that replaces all profane words on a website with `***`.
Right now, I have a huge JS array with all the profane words (2k+ words).
I'm using a for loop to loop over each word in the `profaneWords` array and replace any instance of a matching word with `***`:

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < profaneWords.length; i++) {
      let element = profaneWords[i];
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll(
        element,
        "***"
      );
    }
```

With this, it takes about 5 minutes for my browser to search and replace all instances of all the profane words on a website, with `***`. But, before it is done mapping over the words, no changes are made to the website. So for the 5 minutes, it looks like nothing is happening.

I tested this method with another array that was much smaller (10 words) and the replacing was almost instant.

Is there a better way I could go about implementing this for my array with over 2000 elements?

Comment: Beware the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) - it's a [clbuttic mistake](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-) to be over-eager with what is considered "profane".

Comment: @VLAZ, thanks for this. The array contains profane words from 27 languages, hence the large size. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using RegExp?

```js
const str = 'Waiting on ass, asset , and tit titillation, ass.';
const profaneWords = ['ass', 'tit'];


const regex = new RegExp('\\b'+profaneWords.join('\\b|\\b')+'\\b', 'g');
var newstr =  str.replace(regex, '***');
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: Now just pray that the website doesn't use anything considered a "profane word" in its markup. Classes, IDs, file names, maybe even actual code can all fall victim to this replacement and destroy how a site works in the process